# Laravel Passport: No response when requesting auth Tokens?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I've been struggling for a while to get a response from requesting tokens in Laravel Passport like it's loading forever without a response, no errors nothing!

[image]

This is the code in the controller I've used(from the documentation):

```
protected function login(Request $request)
{

    ...

    $response = Http::asForm()->post('http://localhost:8004/oauth/token', [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => '6',
        'client_secret' => 'GQBBrsDJaV6GgO4uIoXUxOhgp7l7qdlnpB1Bpk5B',
        'username' => 'test@test.com',
        'password' => '123',
       'scope' => '',
    ]);
    
    return $response->json();
}
```

On the other hand when I directly request tokens `oauth/token`. it surprisingly works just fine and returns the response.

[image]

Is there anything I'm missing? please help me out on this!

Comment: use different ports

Comment: @JohnLobo, how???

Comment: now you are using same port .so run php artisan serve --port=8001 and Http::asForm()->post('http://localhost:8001/oauth/token',

Comment: Same. no response, it's just loading @JohnLobo

Comment: You should not use the password grant. It is very unsafe...

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden, what should I do then? it's just for testing.

Comment: Use the correct grant for [your use-case](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/images/grants.min.svg).

Comment: then why is it working when requesting `localhost:8004/auth/token` directly from postman with the same credentials?